# Trying to make a random pixel in a bitmap a new color, but it is giving an error why

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

It is in a view so the setBackground method should be fine, and I am passing Color.BLUE, which is definitely a proper int.

```
    public void changeRandomPixel(int color) 
    {
         Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(intialBitmap, 10, 10, true);
            int[] pixels = new int[resizedBitmap.getHeight()* resizedBitmap.getWidth()];
            resizedBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0,  resizedBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,  resizedBitmap.getWidth(),  resizedBitmap.getHeight());

            Random rand = new Random();

            pixels[rand.nextInt(100)] = color;          

            resizedBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0,  resizedBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,  resizedBitmap.getWidth(),  resizedBitmap.getHeight());

            Drawable background = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resizedBitmap);
            setBackground(background);
    }
```

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:867)

android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14292)

 E/AndroidRuntime(703):  at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14198)


E/AndroidRuntime(703):  jeffery.kesselman.dragonflamebars.ColorView.changeRandomPixel(ColorView.java:102)

Comment: i think edit your question and paste complete exception better, also show which line is 102